# HttpModule invoke in GAC

Tags: c#, asp.net, registration, gac, httpmodule

I just copied the class which was given in the URL https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms227673%28v=vs.85%29.aspx  and created HttpModule and registered this HttpModule in web.config under  section as said below.

```
        <httpModules>
<add name="HelloWorldModule" type="HelloWorldModule, MyAssembly" />      
</httpModules>
```

I deployed my DLL in GAC and restarted the IIS, but “Init(HttpApplication application)” has not been called while accessing any of my ASPX file.

Then, I registered HttpModule in web.config under  Section as said below.

```
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
  <add name="HelloWorldModule" type="HelloWorldModule, MyAssembly" />
  </modules>
```

As a practice, We will not copy any of the DLL in our web application so far, instead all the DLL’s will be deployed in GAC. HttpModule implementation can’t invoke from the DLL which is deployed in GAC?

Comment: Why are you installing this into the GAC? What was your thinking for that?

Comment: I was added custom HttpModule implementation to our existing Project and this DLL was already deployed in GAC. I just want to stick with existing deployment behavior. I cannot propose to deply DLL into bin folder now as our application is already in production